# find which row duplicates which row in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame like this:

```
data.frame(matrix(c(11:13, 21:23, 11:13, 11:13, 31:33, 41:43, 31:33), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))
```

Now I want to know which row is a duplicate of which row, returning an index vector with the lowest row number that is duplicated. if a row is not a duplicate of a previous row, it should get the next available index.
In this example the output should be:

```
c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3)
```

I can achieve this by looping across all pairs of rows, but there must be an efficient way of doing this.

Unfortunately, `duplicated` only shows which rows are duplicates, but not WHICH row they duplicate exactly. Is there a function that could help here?

Comment: Your desired output does not seem to match your sample data. Can you double-check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
# Your data
d <- data.frame(matrix(c(11:13, 21:23, 11:13, 11:13, 31:33, 41:43, 31:23), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3))

# Indices of unique rows 
idx <- as.numeric(factor(apply(d, 1, paste, collapse = "_"), 
                         levels = unique(apply(d, 1, paste, collapse = "_"))));
print(idx);
[1] 1 2 1 1 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: yes, that works great! I now see that I made a typo, the last row should have been 31:33 (I mistyped it as 31:23). Your coded produces the correct result.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative using the `grouping` function in the newer versions of R.

Get the order of rows where identical values are placed next to each other:

```
grs = do.call(grouping, dat)
```

And manipulate the "attributes" of the result to get the wanted outcome:

```
ends = attr(grs, "ends")
rep(seq_along(ends), c(ends[1], diff(ends)))[order(grs)]
#[1] 1 2 1 1 3 4 3
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can use `group_indices` from `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::group_indices(df, X1, X2, X3)
# [1] 1 2 1 1 3 4 3
```

Where `X1, X2` and `X3` are the column names of your data frame.

Comment: this is definitely the most concise version, and easy to read. How would you use it if you didn't know the column names are X1, X2, X3?

Comment: Ah, never mind: `dplyr::group_indices_(df, .dots = colnames(df))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `.GRP` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := .GRP , .(X1, X2, X3)]$grp
#[1] 1 2 1 1 3 4 3
```